# Using env variable in ansible_python_interpreter variable

Tags: ansible

How do I use ${USER} in ansible_python_interpreter variable?

In a deploy.yml I have several tasks and first task installs python into /local/${USER}/venv. Follow up task should use installed python not the one from my own env.
I tried different combinations, those did not work.

deploy.yml

```
- name: use installed python
  host: localhost
  vars_files:
    - settings.yml
  vars:
    # commented items did not work neither here nor in settings.yml
    # ansible_python_interpreter: "/local/{{lookup('env', 'USER')}}/venv/bin/python"                                                                                          
    # ansible_python_interpreter: "/local/${USER}/venv/bin/python"                                                                                                            
    # venv_dir defined in settings.yml
    # ansible_python_interpreter: "{{venv_dir}}/bin/python"
    # hardcoded worked:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/local/myuser/bin/python"
```

The error something like:

```
"/bin/sh: {{venv_dir}}/bin/python: No such file or directory\n"
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: {{venv_dir}}/bin/python: No such file or directory\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
```

settings.yml:

```
---
root_dir: "/local/{{lookup('env', 'USER')}}"
venv_dir: "{{root_dir}}/venv/"
```

Note: moving ansible_python_interpreter into settings.yml does not help.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `ansible_python_interpreter` is not templated under the hood.

You can use `set_fact` workaround:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # default Python here
    - shell: echo hello
    - set_fact:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /local/{{lookup('env', 'USER')}}/venv/bin/python
    # modified Python here
    - shell: echo hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Globally, use the `interpreter_python` key in the `[defaults]` section of `ansible.cfg`

interpreter_python=/usr/bin/python2.7